# Update query not working properly in java

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, jsp

This is a servlet for adding a new user to a table.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
    String dob = request.getParameter("dob");
    String gen = request.getParameter("gen");
    String mem_type = request.getParameter("mem");
    String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
    String addr = request.getParameter("addr");
    long number = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("c_no"));
    String loginID = request.getParameter("loginID");
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    try {
        Date dobb = sdf.parse(dob);
        sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dobb.getDate());
    }
    catch(ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String name = firstname+" "+lastname;

    Connection conn = null;

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/library", "root", "asdfghjkl");

        PreparedStatement updatequery = (PreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO librarian(Librarian Name,Gender,Address,Date Of Birth,Login ID,Contact Number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        updatequery.setString(1, name);
        updatequery.setString(2, gen);
        updatequery.setString(3, addr);
        updatequery.setDate(4, sqlDate);
        updatequery.setString(5, loginID);
        updatequery.setLong(6, number);

        int i = updatequery.executeUpdate();

        out.println(i+"Inserted.");

        conn.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am trying to insert a new row in the table and used the above code but it isn't working. Please help me find the error in the program.

> The **JSP** code is below :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#d1{
position:relative;
bottom:0    

}

</style>

</head>

<jsp:include page="header.html"/>

<body>
<div>
<form class="page" method="post" action="RegisterPage">

First Name : <input name="firstname">

<br><br>

Last Name : <input name="lastname">

<br><br>

Date of Birth : <input name="dob" type="date">

<br><br>

Gender : 
<input type="radio" name="gen" value="Male">Male 
<input type="radio" name="gen" value="Female">Female 

<br><br>

Membership Type :
<input type="radio" name="mem" value="Librarian">Librarian
<input type="radio" name="mem" value="Member">Member

<br><br>

Father's Name : <input name="fname">

<br><br>    

Address <input name="addr">

<br><br>

Contact Number : <input name="c_no" type="text">

<br><br>

Email ID : <input name="loginID" type="email">

<br><br>

Username : <input name="username">

<br><br>

Password : <input name="password" type="password">

<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Register">

</form>
</div>
</body>
<div id="d1">
<jsp:include page="footer.html"/>
</div>
</html>
```

There are 7 columns in the table.The first one is an id with auto-increment and rest are normal columns namely Name,gender,address,Date of birth, login ID,contact number.

I am getting the following error in the console:
     com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error 
    in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
    version for the right syntax to use near 'login table(Login 
    ID,Username,Password) VALUES ('abc@xyz.com','asdfghjkl','asdfg' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Use this line instead of yours :

**PreparedStatement updatequery = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO librarian(Name,gender,address,Date_of_birth,login_ID,contact_number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");**

**Always remember** whenever you have auto_increment field in your table, you must specify the column names while inserting into the table

Check for your setString() method, **for loginID & number, it should be setInt()**

So next thing is Date. from jsp page, you will receive date which will be of type java.Util, But at the time of updating/inserting into database, it should be of type java.sql.Date . So make this change :

```
String dateOfBirth = request.getParameter("dob");  // string format
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = null;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        try {
            Date dobb = sdf.parse(dateOfBirth);   // parsing into Date format
            sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dobb.getDate());  // parsing java.Util.Date into java.sql.Date format
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Finally insert/update to DB using

```
updatequery.setDate(4, sqlDate );
```

Thanks

Comment: @JatinBisht Can you show me the query you written while creating librarian table ..I mean you "create table" query

Comment: I did it on wamp server so I didn't used any query I created it graphically.

Comment: Ok I will try this at my machine, give me some time

Comment: @JatinBisht it is working fine at my end. Did you got any exception?

Comment: No exception that's why I am unable to point out the mistake.

Comment: @JatinBisht is all the coulmns are varchar() ? ..you are using setString() methood for number,loginID columns also

Comment: What datatype should i use for date??

Comment: you can use Date as a datatype in database, and the method to insert date will be setDate()

Comment: Actually it is giving an error telling can't typecast from java sql date to java util date

Comment: Can I update it in answer? You will have util date in your servlet, and at the time of updating in database, you will need to cast it into sql date.

Comment: @JatinBisht Updated the answer.

Comment: no and i have type-casted it into a java.sql date but its still not working.

Comment: No error no exception. That's why I am not able to figure out the problem

Comment: Can you please edit update your question with updated code?

Comment: Ok first thing in the morning.

Comment: Yes sure...no problem

Comment: It is giving an sql Syntax error exception in the console.

Comment: The column name in table never contains whitespaces, "Librarian name" is not valid, I think thats why it is giving error, try using  "Librarian_name"

Comment: Also look at other column names with white spaces

Comment: I have done it in a query with spaces and it is working fine. It was a select query.

Comment: Ohh okay, can you show me the exception you ar getting

Comment: It is written at end of the question  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'login table(Login ID,Username,Password) VALUES ('abc@xyz.com','asdfghjkl','asdfg' at line 1

Comment: That is simple exception..can we talk on mail? this is not right place to chat

Comment: your email ID please.

Comment: sforsujit1044@gmail.com